# Isomorphic JS - variable is not available on client

Tags: javascript, node.js, isomorphic-javascript

I'm currently working on a project which uses some shared JS between client and server. The tech stack includes Node v6, Webpack, React etc.

There's a directory "shared" from which server and client require a file called *rules.js*. On the first render which happens on the server side, the rules variable declared in *rules.js* is set with a value from DB (I've done console.log to verify it's really filled with data).

Then on client side some component might require this *rules.js* file and get the rules variable. However, when I console.log the variable, it's empty.

The rules file looks similar to this:

```
// shared/rules.js

let rules;

// This is called on server to set the value
exports.setData = function(data) {
  rules = data;
}

exports.rules = rules;
```

Do you have any idea what could be wrong? Should I choose different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the file may be shared by both the client and server, the *instance* of the class is not. So, anything you do to it on the server will not persist on the client, and vice versa.

**One idea available is that of "dehydrating" and "rehydrating" your state.**

**server.js**

```
// implemented in server to dehydrate your state
import rules from '../shared/rules';
let dehydratedRules = JSON.stringify(rules.rules);

let html = renderToString(<App/>);

// now in your render call
res.render('yourTemplateFile', {html, dehydratedRules});
```

**yourTemplateFile**

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">var __RULES__ = {{dehydratedRules}};
...
```

**client.js**

```
// implemented in client to rehydrate your state
import rules from '../shared/rules';

let parsedRules = JSON.parse(__RULES__);
delete window.__RULES__;

// set the rehydrated data back in the class
rules.setData(parsedRules);
```

[Checkout this SO answer utilizing an analogy from Back to the Future to explain dehydrating/rehydrating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33790716/4288327).